# Cheap mobo + RAM for i7 13700k

Tags: motherboard, memory

What to look for and what to avoid when looking for motherboard and RAM for 13700k? The goal is to get the most bang for the buck.

As I understand, factory settings of this CPU are already sky high, so one doesn't lose much without OC, like B660. If any, undervolting is due - do all mobos offer options to tweak CPU voltage? Is staying in Gear1 still relevant for DDR4? If so, what it the top reasonable speed to aim for DDR4 modules?